# Homescreen on Nexus 4 (Lollipop) looks different compared to images of stock Lollipop

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

I installed Lollipop on a Nexus 4 and I noticed some differences from the videos and images of stock Lollipop that I've seen before. Mainly the status/notification and navigational bars are black (they should be transparent). Also, the design of the folders on the home screen is different (my folders have a black background while it should be white). You can see some examples in the images.

[image: Black bars] [image: Black folder]
<sup>"Black bars" / "Black Folder" (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Does anyone know where's the problem?

Comment: How did you flash the update?

Comment: OTA, a notification appeared prompting to update!

Comment: FWIW, my Nexus 4 looks different to what you are showing. Is it possible that you have the new OS with the old Google Now launcher? Check whether there's an update to Google / Google Search / whatever it's called these days available in the play store.

Comment: I don't have Google Now launcher on my phone right now. The home screen look and feel should come with Lollipop, not the custom launcher which as far as I know is intended for non Nexus devices. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The launcher (or, more generically, the currently focused app) definitely influences this. Nova launcher lets you toggle the transparency on and off, for example. I would wager your launcher is the culprit here. Especially since your second example is the design of the folders, which is absolutely controlled by the launcher.

Comment: I installed the Google Now launcher. That was it. Thank you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Lollipop's notification bar is not transparent in Nexus 4](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89221/android-lollipops-notification-bar-is-not-transparent-in-nexus-4)

Answer (score 2):

Transparent notification bar / softkeys background, app drawer opening and closing animations are part of [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher). Install it and you are good to go.

Comment: Other launchers like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) support transparent bars as well, if you're looking for more customizability.

Answer (score 1):

For what is IMO the purest stock Android experience, download the [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) from the Play Store. Sure, there are other launchers out there, but this is straight from Google.

It replaces the old launcher and will give you the transparency you're looking for, along with the white backgrounds and other Material Design elements.

Comment: -1. He's using Nexus, which is also Google

Comment: I was referring to the launcher, not the device.

The Google Now Launcher is from Google, whereas launchers such as Nova Launcher are not, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: He just got Lollipop on a Nexus device. I'm 99% sure it's running stock launcher

Comment: You're probably technically correct that it's running the stock launcher, but Google intends for the Google Now Launcher to replace the stock launcher, even on Nexus devices, in order for the full Lollipop experience (i.e., Material Design).