# Android Lollipop's notification bar is not transparent in Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, launcher, notification-bar

I had updated my Nexus 4 with Android 5.0 OTA update last week. I observed that the notification bar is not transparent. I see some reviews of Android Lollipop (Nexus 4) in YouTube and as I remembered correctly the notification bar was transparent. Is anybody having the same issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compared to Nexus 5, Lollipop stock launcher on Nexus 4 doesn't have transparency on the notification bar.

Instead, the one with transparency is [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher) (originally known as Google Experience Launcher). After installing the launcher, you can switch between those two from Settings > Home.

[image: Lollipop stock launcher] [image: Lollipop GEL launcher]

```
Lollipop stock launcher      Lollipop Google Now Launcher
```