# Android Lollipop Google Now Launcher is not fully transparent

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, google, launcher

As seen in the screenshot, Google Now Launcher status bar is not fully transparent. It has shadows in my phone. (Moto G XT1032, Lollipop 5.0.1)

[image]

But the official screenshots does not have that shadow.

[image]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://www.android.com/new/images/phones/moto-g.png))</sub>

Is it just me? How to remove that?

Comment: Your wallpaper probably has a gradient at each edge. Pick a different one. See how it looks then.

Comment: @eldarerathis : I've tried different wallpapers. Event the same wallpaper used in the official screenshot. No luck.

Comment: It's always been slightly tinted for me in Lollipop on a few devices, supposedly to prevent burn in, and to highlight the bar and when items slide under it as part of material design they are designed to be darker looking, so a slight gradient would support that. I wouldn't believe anything pre-rendered that I see in advertising. You just have to look up Watchdogs the game or similar to see what companies do. That wallpaper does have a gradient too which makes it clearer.

Comment: @RossC: FWIW, it's fully transparent on my N5. Could be some kind of vendor- or ROM-specific config, though, I suppose. I know there's a config flag that disables the transparency completely, but I'm not sure about one that would add a gradient. Either that or it's the launcher, maybe.

Comment: @eldarerathis I can't believe I didn't factor the launcher in, I'm using Nova here on Lollipop and it is indeed completely transparent.

Comment: I'd suspect it's because you're using Google Now Launcher, not stock launcher. The symptom is really similar to [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89221/android-lollipops-notification-bar-is-not-transparent-in-nexus-4?rq=1). Could you try uninstall the launcher/change to stock launcher? AFAIK, Google Now Launcher for Lollipop adds a gradient (for unknown reason), while Lollipop stock launcher depends on the vendor (N4 has black bar, N5 is fully transparent).